# table design more rows, more columns, or more tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it better to have fewer tables with more columns or more tables with fewer columns?

For example lets say I have one table where the columns are
Date, Hour, Market, Price

Hour just means the hour of the day (ie. 1-24).  Market is a three character code either DAM or RTM.  Price is the important value to track.

Would it be better to instead have two tables with just three columns where one of the tables is the subset where market is DAM and the other is RTM?

Another idea is to make the table with Date, Hour, DAMPrice, RTMPrice.  Would this be the best given that most selects would be simpler with this approach?

The most used SELECT is to take the difference of the DAMPrice from the RTMPrice which now works with joins on the same table.

Comment: If there are any possibility that you would add more markets later, you should store the markets as data in the table, not in column or table names. However, I would have used two tables, one for market names (and market IDs), and one for the data (Date, Hour, Market_id, Price). Then you can add another marked just by adding one row to the market table.

Comment: If there is no possibility of adding more markets then is it still better to do this or would it then be better to use separate columns for each market

Comment: Separate rtables. Because filtering by market is then basically a nubmer compare instead of a string compare - that is faster. I also doubt date + hour should be separate columns.

Comment: A number compare is not always faster than a character compare.  The comparison time really comes down the size of the data type.  Generally integer comparisons are faster because they are only 4 bytes this column could be stored in 3 bytes as char(3) though.  The speed difference is minor but on a large scale there is less to read off disk, less bytes to compare afterward and the index would be more narrow in an indexed situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a design perspective, it's usually better to normalize your data to reduce redundancy. Usually this means more tables with fewer columns.

In practice, however, you'll get better performance if you minimize the number of join operations. So it may be acceptable to have redundant data if you want to speed up your reads. In this situation you would have fewer tables with more columns.

I recommend choosing the better design first, then optimizing for performance later if necessary.

Comment: *In practice, however, you'll get better performance if you minimize the number of join operation* Unless of course you need the distinct values of some of the attributes. Then its much slower.

Comment: Additionally, one can use a polyglot approach and have an optimized NoSQL database for some data.